# Python Pandas: Replace values in one column with values from another column based on a specified condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace values in one column with values from another column based on a specified condition. So for every row in a pandas dataframe, where a cell value in column 1== Not Specified, I want to replace that cell with the value from column 2.

Taking an example:

I want to replace the "Not specified" cells in the "subtype" column (see below table) to the values in the "type" column.

Hence  "Not specified" to be replaced with C and D, respectively.

Please help to advise which line of code to achieve that. 
[image]

Comment: So where is your code you have so far?

Comment: Sorry for not including the code. Not much code done so far, i just created a data frame from an excel file. Anyhow, question has been answered. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['Subtype'].eq('Not Specified'),'Subtype']=df.loc[df['Subtype'].eq('Not Specified'),'Type']
```

or [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)

```
df['Subtype']=df['Subtype'].mask(df['Subtype'].eq('Not Specified'),df['Type'])
```

or [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df['Subtype']=df['Type'].where(df['Subtype'].eq('Not Specified'),df['Subtype'])
```

Comment: I used the last option you suggested. it worked. THANKS ALOT!